# PHP: date() with format string does not work

Tags: javascript, php, date

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$dateiname = date("Y.m.d");
echo "<script>alert($dateiname)</script>";
```

As long as I DON'T use any signs in the format string ("Ymd"), the alert is showing. On single point and the alert does NOT open.

BUT: on other servers the code works as it should. So there is probably some setting that interferes. But which and where?

Any ideas?

Thx
Oliver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With symbols (`.`) it becomes a string so it needs to be quoted. Without the `.`s it is an integer and integers don't need to be quoted.

```
<?php
$dateiname = date("Y.m.d");
echo "<script>alert('$dateiname')</script>";
```

Additionally that should have returned a console error. I'd recommend looking over https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open if unfamliar with the developer console.

For another example compare the results of:

```js
console.log(1);
```

```js
    console.log(1a);
```

```js
console.log('1a');
```

Comment: Amazing, the speed of qualified help around here. That was exactly the problem: string or not string...

Thx